# Error in custom java class imported into Oracle EBS r12

Tags: oracle12c, oracleforms, oracle-ebs

I have a custom java class imported into Oracle forms in Oracle EBS R12, but when I am going to run the java functionality in the application it gives me the following error:

> exception:java.lang. exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: getsipbyname_proxy/proxy/GET_SIP_by_NamePortClient

Could you help me to know why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you use a getsipbyname or something like that in your java class?
From which class does that come from?

Comment: Yes, that is used. It seems that I have the problem because the EBS forms r12 is not able to find the .jar

Comment: Did you include the class in your application server CLASSPATH?

Comment: I have added the .jar file that contains the java class in the classpath element of the $CONTEXT_FILE of EBS. 
Summarizing, I have added a java class within a form, this form is executed in ebs r12.2.6 and when the form is executed it shows the error message saying that the definition of the class is not found.